# Android EditText Color Issue

Tags: android

So my current APK uploaded to the Play Store doesn't have this color issue but while debugging today I've encountered this on older Android devices but I haven't touched the EditText background or colors at all... Has anyone seen this before? I've been googling all day and can't find anything.[image]

Comment: Did you use an image file?

Comment: No I didn't, this is what one of the xml looks like for the top EditText
<EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit_title"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                />

Comment: You will have to explicitly set the background for older devices. Have you included 
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`

Comment: Yes I have both of those dependencies and my current APK on the play store doesn't have the color issues even without explicitly setting backgrounds, I'm going to be trying Er. Arjun saini's answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Bug of Android studio 2.2 preview which are solved in Android studio preview 4

I recommended you to update the gradle with new version

**Android studio 2.2 Preview 4**

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview4available

**or with Gradle 2.1.0**

> ```
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
> ```